# How can you pattern match for several types, one of which is required, ala rust enums?

Tags: kotlin

I need a variable, which can be one of several required values, of different types. (Let's say either a post, comment, or community)

In rust, you're able to have enum data structures, which can have various types, then extract their inner info via a match statement: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum.html

The only comparable thing I've found in Kotlin, is the Either type, but this is limited to two values. Is there anything in Kotlin comparable?

Comment: [Sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from @IR42 works, not as cleanly as rust, but here it is:

```
sealed class ItemType {
  class PostItem(val item: Post): ItemType()
  class CommentItem(val item: Comment): ItemType()
}
...
val x = ItemType.PostItem(post)
when(x) {
  is ItemType.PostItem -> x.item.post ...
  is ItemType.CommentItem -> x.item.comment ...
}
```